# How do I view "NOTE" level diagnostics when doing annotation processing?

Tags: kotlin, annotation-processing

## Overview

I'm trying to familiarise myself with Kotlin for a project I'm working on and getting to grips with annotation processing. I'd like to know how I can view diagnostics when the annotation processor runs so I can easily see what's happening at different stages within the process.

## Environment

- Windows 10 64-bit
- IntelliJ 2018.2.5 as my IDE
- Gradle 4.10.2 (configured with kapt plugin for annotation processing)
- Kotlin 1.2.71

## Details

I've found that I can access a `messenger` object within my processor that lets me output diagnostic messages. This is what I've implemented so far:

```
override fun process(annotations: MutableSet<out TypeElement>?, roundEnv: RoundEnvironment): Boolean {
    roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(ElementaryNode::class.java).forEach {
        if (it !is ExecutableElement) {
            processingEnv.messager.printMessage(
                    Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR,
                    "Cannot generate elementary node from non-executable element"
            )
            return false
        }

        processingEnv.messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.WARNING, "Test that this works")

        val packageName = processingEnv.elementUtils.getPackageOf(it).toString()
        val definition = ElementaryNodeDefinition.fromFunction(it)
        outputElementaryNode(definition, packageName)
    }

    return true
}
```

If I run `gradle build` from the command-line, I see that this outputs the warning-level diagnostic messages:

```
$ gradle build
...
> Task :sample-main:kaptGenerateStubsKotlin
w: warning: Test that this works
w: warning: Test that this works
w: warning: Test that this works
w: warning: Test that this works
w: warning: Test that this works
w: warning: Test that this works
w: warning: Test that this works
...
```

However, I don't see any diagnostics appear if I output these diagnostics at any lower level, such as `Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE`.

I've tried trawling the javac documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html) and looking at the source code of projects that also do annotation processing (like [this one](https://github.com/airbnb/DeepLinkDispatch/blob/master/deeplinkdispatch-processor/src/main/java/com/airbnb/deeplinkdispatch/Documentor.java)) but I can't find anything that explains how to view diagnostic messages at this level.

In case it's helpful, this is the `build.gradle.kts` file for the sub-project containing my annotation processor:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    kotlin("kapt")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    implementation("com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc4")
    implementation("com.squareup:kotlinpoet:1.0.0-RC1")
    implementation(project(":model"))
    kapt("com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc4")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

This is the `build.gradle.kts` file for my "sample-main" project that contains my entry-point:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    kotlin("kapt")
}

dependencies {
    kapt(project(":node-generation"))
    implementation(project(":node-generation"))
    implementation(project(":model"))
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Comment: Did you try the `--debug` switch of gradle? There you can show the debug log level, but I'm not sure if this includes your note log level

Comment: @rekire Thanks. I'd tried that earlier and it wasn't working, but now I'm trying it and it does. I'm not sure what I've done differently. Also, I'm sure before I was getting output on each run of `gradle build`, whereas now I need to clean first and rebuild to get that output (which makes sense, but I'm wondering why it's changed now).

Comment: Great that you got it now working. I know that strange feeling that it didn't work before and after changing some code and rolling it back it starts working.

Answer (score 2):

Run with the --debug option

```
gradle build --debug
```

Unfortunately, you may discover that all the other debug logging that comes along with that option is so verbose that you cannot find your own output and use of the option isn't practical. I'm bummed to say that in our case we use `WARNING` level for all none-error level log messages in our annotations processor.